# How does Netty behave behind front-end HTTP servers in Play Framework Application

Tags: playframework-2.0, netty

As per the document available online, we can use front-end HTTP server for load balancing and multiple Netty can serve from behind. My understanding so far is, because of multiple threads Netty is able to accept many requests simultaneously. I am really confuse about, to get the full advantage of Netty, shouldn't front-end HTTP server also be capable of using multiple threads to accept multiple requests simultaneously? If not, will this scenario nullify Netty advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty is an *asynchronous NIO framework*, for writing network applications in Java. Its not just *multiple threads*, but also the non-blocking IO that allows Netty to handle large number of connections with a handful of threads.

Regarding the front-end HTTP load-balancer and reverse proxy: **Yes**, it *must* not be the bottleneck, and must be able handle throughput and connections that your Netty server pool behind the load balancer would. Typically, if you thinking of using Nginx for load balancing, then it already leverage non-blocking IO, and you should get a high performance out of these. If you are using Apache HTTPD, then it supports blocking I/O model based on the classic Java I/O and non-blocking, event driven I/O model based on Java NIO. It can be tuned to work either way.